# How do I get open price for NASDAQ in IBKR python API?

Tags: python, interactive-brokers

I am getting last price, close price. But for tickType == 14 I am not getting any data.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/tick_types.html), you need to have a "market data subscription to the native exchange of the instrument" in order to access Open Tick (tickType == 14) data. Do you have this?

If you have a subscription, then you may have a coding error. In this case, please provide your code for `reqMktData` and the `tickPrice` callback.

EDIT: I see your problem. `reqMktData` provides a lot of data by default, but if you want tickType = 14, you need to specifically identify it in the third argument. Try running this code:

```
app.reqMktData(3, contract_NASDAQ, "14", True, False, [])
```

Comment: yes, i have market data subscription to NASDAQ. It is returning last price (tickId = 4) and close price (tickId = 9). It seems Open is not shown in TWS workstation also.

Comment: Output: 
TickPrice. TickerId: 3 tickType: LAST Price: 8979.66 
TickPrice. TickerId: 3 tickType: CLOSE Price: 8979.66 
TickPrice. TickerId: 3 tickType: BID Price: -1.0 
TickPrice. TickerId: 3 tickType: ASK Price: -1.0

Comment: def tickPrice(self, reqId, tickType, price, attrib):
print("TickPrice. TickerId:", reqId, "tickType:", TickTypeEnum.to_str(tickType), "Price:", price, end=' ''\n')

Comment: app.reqMktData(3, contract_NASDAQ, "", True, False, [])

Comment: Tried this. Not working. It seems they do not have open data for indices. Is there a way to get the first traded price?

Comment: I don't know. I've never looked for index data. I'd ask your question at the TWS API forum at https://groups.io/g/twsapi/topics. Good luck!

Comment: what is "contract_NASDAQ"? how are you defining this?